# Stateless EJB isn't aware of roles declared in web.xml

Tags: glassfish, ejb, ejb-3.1, glassfish-4

I'm actually running into a role propagation problem and I need help.
I am using Glassfish 4.0 and I'm deploying a war containing a `JAX-RS` resource and an `EJB` with a remote and a local view for testing purposes.

I have declared roles in my `web.xml` and `glassfish-web.xml` Deployment Descriptors, linked to a File Realm in Glassfish.
Those roles are correctly used by the `JAX-RS` resource, but the `EJB` doesn't seem to see them.

I will show you the files I'm using, and then the results of the different call outputs I've tested so far.

**TL/DR : Sorry for the extremely long post. Please go to PART II / Test 2**

## PART I : The code

### The `glassfish-web.xml` Deployment Descriptor

```
<!DOCTYPE glassfish-web-app PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Servlet 3.0//EN" "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-web-app_3_0-1.dtd">
<glassfish-web-app>
    <context-root>/war-test-4</context-root>
        <security-role-mapping>
        <role-name>test</role-name>
        <group-name>test</group-name>
    </security-role-mapping>
    <security-role-mapping>
        <role-name>test2</role-name>
        <group-name>test2</group-name>
    </security-role-mapping>
    <security-role-mapping>
        <role-name>authenticated</role-name>
        <group-name>authenticated</group-name>
    </security-role-mapping>
</glassfish-web-app>
```

### The `web.xml` Deployment Descriptor

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
    <display-name>war-test-4</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <description>JAX-RS Tools Generated - Do not modify</description>
        <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        <security-role-ref>
            <description>Test</description>
            <role-name>test</role-name>
            <role-link>test</role-link>
        </security-role-ref>
        <security-role-ref>
            <description>Auth users</description>
            <role-name>authenticated</role-name>
            <role-link>authenticated</role-link>
        </security-role-ref>
        <security-role-ref>
            <description>Test2</description>
            <role-name>test2</role-name>
            <role-link>test2</role-link>
        </security-role-ref>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/jaxrs/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>Admin Resources</web-resource-name>
            <description>Administration resources</description>
            <url-pattern>/jaxrs/*</url-pattern>
            <http-method>GET</http-method>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <description>TEST</description>
            <role-name>test</role-name>
            <role-name>test2</role-name>
            <role-name>authenticated</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
    <login-config>
        <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
        <realm-name>test-realm</realm-name>
    </login-config>
    <security-role>
        <description>Test</description>
        <role-name>test</role-name>
    </security-role>
    <security-role>
        <description>Auth users</description>
        <role-name>authenticated</role-name>
    </security-role>
    <security-role>
        <description>Test2</description>
        <role-name>test2</role-name>
    </security-role>
</web-app>
```

### The stateless EJB `SessionBeanTest.java`

```
/**
 * Session Bean implementation class SessionBeanTest
 */
@Stateless(mappedName = "SessionBeanTest")
//@RolesAllowed({"authenticated"})
//@DeclareRoles({"authenticated","test","test2"})
public class SessionBeanTest implements SessionBeanRemote, SessionBeanLocal {

    @Resource
    private SessionContext sessionContext;

    @Override
    public String get() {
        return MessageFormat
                .format("EJB Call by :{0} authenticated? : {1} / test2 ? : {2} / test ? : {3}",
                        sessionContext.getCallerPrincipal().getName(),
                        sessionContext.isCallerInRole("authenticated"),
                        sessionContext.isCallerInRole("test2"), sessionContext.isCallerInRole("test"));
    }
}
```

### My JAX-RS Service `AccessTest.java`

```
@Path("access")
//@DeclareRoles({/*"authenticated","test",*/"test2"})
@Stateless
public class AccessTest {

    @Inject
    private SessionBeanLocal testBean;
    @GET
    @Path("1")
    public Response test(@Context HttpServletRequest req){
        return Response.ok(MessageFormat
                .format("JAX-RS Call by :{0} authenticated? : {1} / test2 ? : {2} / test ? : {3}",
            req.getUserPrincipal().getName(),
                    req.isUserInRole("authenticated"),
                    req.isUserInRole("test2"),
                    req.isUserInRole("test"))).build();

    }

    @GET
    @Path("2")
    public Response test2(){
        return Response.ok(testBean.get()).build();
    }
}
```

As you've probably noticed, **I have commented `@DeclareRoles` and `@RolesAllowed` annotations in both my EJB and my JAX-RS resource.** I also have 2 URIs in my JAX-RS service. One is directly giving the user informations and roles, and the other uses the EJB to retrieve the same information. **Both should return the exact same output if a user is logged.**

## PART II : The tests

Now, using a web-service tester (Paw on Mac, Curl based, very useful!), I'm accessing both URIs:

### Test 1 : No user is logged in

**Output for URI `/jaxrs/access/1` with no user**

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
X-Powered-By: Servlet/3.1 JSP/2.3 (GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.0  Java/Oracle Corporation/1.7)
```

**Output for URI `/jaxrs/access/2` with no user**

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
X-Powered-By: Servlet/3.1 JSP/2.3 (GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.0  Java/Oracle Corporation/1.7)
```

So far, it seems to work as planned, an authenticated user is required to access the resource.
But have a look at the second test...

### Test 2 : A user with all roles is logged in

**Output for URI `/jaxrs/access/1` with user having all roles**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: Servlet/3.1 JSP/2.3 (GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.0  Java/Oracle Corporation/1.7)

JAX-RS Call by :testadmin authenticated? : true / test2 ? : true / test ? : true
```

**Output for URI `/jaxrs/access/2` with user having all roles**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: Servlet/3.1 JSP/2.3 (GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.0  Java/Oracle Corporation/1.7)

EJB Call by :testadmin authenticated? : **false** / test2 ? : **false** / test ? : **false**
```

This is the part I don't understand. The Roles declared in `web.xml` and `glassfish-web.xml` aren't propagated to the EJB, which is in the same WAR project.

### Test 3 : Uncommenting the `@DeclareRoles` annotation in code

Whether I uncomment the `@DeclareRoles({"authenticated"})` in my EJB or my JAX-RS service, I get the following output :

**Output for URI `/jaxrs/access/1` with user having all roles, `@DeclareRoles` uncommented**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: Servlet/3.1 JSP/2.3 (GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.0  Java/Oracle Corporation/1.7)

JAX-RS Call by :testadmin authenticated? : true / test2 ? : true / test ? : true
```

**Output for URI `/jaxrs/access/2` with user having all roles, `@DeclareRoles` uncommented**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: Servlet/3.1 JSP/2.3 (GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.0  Java/Oracle Corporation/1.7)

EJB Call by :testadmin authenticated? : **true** / test2 ? : **false** / test ? : **false**
```

Only the roles I declare are seen by the EJB, **but the JAX-RS service sees them all**

## PART III : The Remote EJB call

I also have a pure Java client for testing purposes. Here it is :

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        getRemoteService();
    }

    public static void getRemoteService() throws Exception {
        String host = "127.0.0.1";
        String port = "3700";
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("java.naming.factory.initial", "com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory");
        props.setProperty("java.naming.factory.url.pkgs", "com.sun.enterprise.naming");
        props.setProperty("java.naming.factory.state", "com.sun.cobra.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl");
        props.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost", host);
        props.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialPort", port);

        Context amInitial = null;
        amInitial = new InitialContext(props);
        ProgrammaticLogin programmaticLogin = new ProgrammaticLogin();
        programmaticLogin.login("testuser2", "password");
        SessionBeanRemote service = (SessionBeanRemote) amInitial.lookup("SessionBeanTest");
        System.out.println(service.get());
        programmaticLogin.logout();
        programmaticLogin.login("testadmin", "password");
        System.out.println(service.get());
    }
}
```

This client uses `ProgrammaticLogin` interface to log in and use the EJB with CORBA. I'm not planning to use it other than for testing.

First, the client will log in with a limited user, then with a user with all roles.
Here are the test results using this Client :

### Test 1 : Testing the remote EJB with `@DeclareRoles` commented

```
EJB Call by :ANONYMOUS authenticated? : false / test2 ? : false / test ? : false
EJB Call by :ANONYMOUS authenticated? : false / test2 ? : false / test ? : false
```

### Test 2 : Testing the remote EJB with `@DeclareRoles({"authenticated","test","test2"})` uncommented

```
EJB Call by :ANONYMOUS authenticated? : false / test2 ? : false / test ? : false
EJB Call by :ANONYMOUS authenticated? : false / test2 ? : false / test ? : false
```

Here, the users aren't authenticated either. But when I add a `@RolesAllowed` annotation to the EJB I get this:

### Test 3 : Testing the remote EJB with `@DeclareRoles` and `@RolesAllowed({"authenticated"})` added

```
EJB Call by :testuser2 authenticated? : true / test2 ? : true / test ? : false
EJB Call by :testadmin authenticated? : true / test2 ? : true / test ? : true
```

This is all I've tested so far. I don't understand why the roles declared in the Deployment Descriptors are correctly used by the JAX-RS service, but not by the Stateless EJB. I need your help on this, I'm not really into putting boilerplate Roles annotations on every EJB.

Comment: Hi @mrik974 have you found any solution for role propagation and ANONYMOUS issue?

Comment: Nope, and it is still really annoying me. I had to move forward, but if anyone finds a solution I will be very happy to try it out.

Comment: It is so much frustrating and there is no help available at all. All such question I have found on web are not-answered :(

Comment: Hi guys, have you got any solutions? I'm having the same problem with GlassFish 4.1. I even tried to add a glassfish-ejb-jar.xml but it didn't help either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am unaware of either of the [EJB 3.2](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/ejb-3_2-fr-spec/index.html) and [Java EE 7](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/java_ee-7-fr-spec/index.html) specifications mandating or at least recommending compatible implementations' containers to endorse Security Role *declarations* of others. On the contrary, what these documents, to my eye, hint, is that such declarations are constrained --at least from the perspective of "userspace" code-- within the *operational environment* they were defined in.

With regard to your observations:

- GlassFish is a [*JSR-115*](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=115)- (*JACC*-) compatible Application Server. According to §§ 3.1.1 - 3.1.5, §§ 4.2 - 4.3 of that specification, roles declared via `web.xml` and `ejb-jar.xml` elements, or equivalent annotations, are to be "translated" into [`WebRoleRefPermission`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/security/jacc/WebRoleRefPermission.html)s and [`EJBRoleRefPermission`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/security/jacc/EJBRoleRefPermission.html)s, respectively, by the default JACC provider; they are thus disparate. These and a few other Java EE-specific `Permission`s are --at least in theory-- accessible from "userspace" code, e.g. as demonstrated [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/monzillo/entry/using_jacc_to_determine_a) (this approach actually still works for me on GlassFish 4.1).
- *JAX-RS* in Java EE --i.e. *Jersey* in particular-- sits on top of the Servlet infrastructure. This is principally the reason for [`SecurityContext.isUserInRole(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/SecurityContext.html#isUserInRole%28java.lang.String%29) and [`HttpServletRequest.isUserInRole(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#isUserInRole%28java.lang.String%29) being equivalent in this scenario. For a different hypothetical Servlet-independent implementation, however, this would not have been the case, and it would once again be required to define security roles twice.

In conclusion, I don't consider this behaviour a specs violation. It may be counter-intuitive --but that's a different story.

As an aside, I wholeheartedly agree that the great lack of resources on the platform's security facilities, i.e. JACC and JASPIC in particular, is dispiriting; I would at least expect a dedicated chapter on each to be included in the official tutorial. Were it not for [Arjan Tijms's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/472792/arjan-tijms) [extensive](http://arjan-tijms.omnifaces.org/2014/02/jaas-in-java-ee-is-not-universal.html) [collection](http://arjan-tijms.omnifaces.org/2012/11/implementing-container-authentication.html) [of](http://arjan-tijms.omnifaces.org/2014/03/implementing-container-authorization-in.html) [in](http://arjan-tijms.omnifaces.org/2014/12/java-ee-authorization-jacc-revisited.html)-[depth](http://arjan-tijms.omnifaces.org/2015/01/java-ee-authorization-jacc-revisited.html) [articles](http://arjan-tijms.omnifaces.org/2015/03/java-ee-authorization-jacc-revisited.html) on the subject, many of us would still be left in the dark. One can only hope that the new [*JSR-375*](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=375) will help change that --and much more-- without (hopefully!) reinventing the wheel and/or layering everything atop Servlet `Filter`s.

Comment: You are totally right. But as you said, this is really counter-intuitive... Thank you for the link on Arjan Tijm's blog!

Answer (score 1):

A hint to make your web.xml a bit shorter. The following is not need for the Servlet:

```
<security-role-ref>
    <description>Test2</description>
        <role-name>test2</role-name>
        <role-link>test2</role-link>
</security-role-ref>
```

You only should use this if you have a binary Servlet that uses different roles than what your app is using. role-refs already default to the application roles.

Your test looks pretty much like this one: https://github.com/javaee-samples/javaee7-samples/tree/master/jaspic/ejb-propagation

On GlassFish 4.1 (one revision higher than you are using) that test passed if my memory serves me correctly.